# Checking the number in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner web developer
I have problem with checking numbers in JS.

My code:

```
function checkValidateForm() {
        let errorWidth = false;
        let errorHeight = false;
        let errorDepth = false;
        if (parseFloat(cupboardMinWidth) <= parseFloat($('.product-size').val()) && parseFloat(cupboardMaxWidth) >= parseFloat($('.product-size').val())) {
            errorWidth = false;
        } else {
            errorWidth = true;
        }

        if (parseFloat(cupboardMinHeight) <= parseFloat($('.product-height').val()) && parseFloat(cupboardMaxHeight) >= parseFloat($('.product-height').val())) {
            errorHeight = false;
        } else {
            errorHeight = true;
        }

        if (parseFloat(cupboardMinDepth) <= parseFloat($('.product-depth').val()) && parseFloat(cupboardMaxDepth) >= parseFloat($('.product-depth').val())) {
            errorDepth = false;
        } else {
            errorDepth = true;
        }

        if ($('.product-size').val() == "" || $('.product-height').val() == "" || $('.product-depth').val() == "" || errorWidth === true || errorHeight === true || errorDepth === true) {
            $('.product-add-to-basket').attr("disabled", true);
            if (errorWidth === true) {
                $('.product-info-box1').html('Wymagana szerokość to: <b>' + cupboardMinWidth + 'cm -' + cupboardMaxWidth + 'cm </b><br/>');
                $('.product-info-box1').fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $('.product-info-box1').fadeOut("slow");
            }
            if (errorHeight === true) {
                $('.product-info-box2').html('Wymagana wysokość to: <b>' + cupboardMinHeight + 'cm -' + cupboardMaxHeight + 'cm </b><br/>');
                $('.product-info-box2').fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $('.product-info-box2').fadeOut("slow");
            }
            if (errorDepth === true) {
                $('.product-info-box3').html('Wymagana głębokość to: <b>' + cupboardMinDepth + 'cm -' + cupboardMaxDepth + 'cm </b><br/>');
                $('.product-info-box3').fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $('.product-info-box3').fadeOut("slow");
            }
            $('.product-info-error-msg').fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('.product-info-error-msg').fadeOut("slow");
            $('.product-info-box1').hide;
            $('.product-info-box2').hide;
            $('.product-info-box3').hide;
            $('.product-add-to-basket').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }

let productId = 1;

        let cupboardMinWidth = '100.00';


        let cupboardMaxWidth = '250.00';



        let cupboardMinHeight = '100.00';


        let cupboardMaxHeight = '190.00';



        let cupboardMinDepth = '140.00';


        let cupboardMaxDepth = '190.00';
```

My preview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

Wymagana szerokość to: 100.00cm -250.00cm - max width

Wymagana wysokość to: 100.00cm -190.00cm -max height

Wymagana głębokość to: 140.00cm -190.00cm  - max depth

When I add values to my inputs, e.g. 100.5, 120.5 etc. - the dimensions messages are not always hidden.

Why?

When my dimensions meet the ranges - the message should hide, and this is not always the case

How can I repair it?

Comment: your code works, is the execution that is wrong. Now you execute `checkValidateForm` on every input insertion and on page loading

Comment: Seems like you're using an input mask. So on `input` the mask hasn't "fix" the value so before the number becomes `100.5` (again, because of the mask code) it is `1005.`

Comment: yes, maybe this is problem. How can I repair it?

Comment: I add this values: 100.0. 120.0, 140.0 - and  message is visible. When I add next integer to last input: 140.00 - then message is hidden. This is my problem

Comment: A side notes: (1) why `cupboardMinWidth` (for example) is a `string`? (2) Instead of calling `$(a_selector)` over and over again, store it in a variable. e.g. const myElem = $('.my-elem');` and then `myElem.value()`. Or even `const myElemValue = parseFloat($('.my-elem').value());` and then `if (myElemValue > 0 || myElemValue < 100)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will correct it after solving the current problem. cupboard Min Width is no longer a string :)

Comment: Instead of using the native events such as `input`, use the plugin [callbacks](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#callback-examples) e.g. `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the $('.product-size') is empty it'll be parsed by
parseFloat($('.product-size').val()) to NaN, and comparing any number with NaN with any operator will give you false, even comparing NaN with NaN will give you false.

What I suggest is to add events to the inputs, so when the user changes the value they'll be triggered and you can do the verification and show the messages as you want.

```
const size = document.querySelector('.product-size');

size.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
     console.log(event.target.value);
     // You can add the condition here and show your message
})
```